# ViewConfiguration.get NullPointer exception in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Following is the stack trace recieved on Android device name i2 running Android 4.2.2. 
As seen below I believe the root cause for this to happen is cause of the null pointer exception below which is all android api calls. How do I test this and debug this? Help!!!!

### Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.insight/com.example.android.appit.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TabHost
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TabHost
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.UILibrary.CustomUI.Activities.BaseFragmentActivity.setContentView(BaseFragmentActivity.java:90)
at com.UILibrary.CustomUI.TabPager.FragmentTabsPager.onCreate(FragmentTabsPager.java:59)
at com.example.android.appit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:370)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:285)
at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:323)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3241)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3286)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:436)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.TabHost.<init>(TabHost.java:80)
... 26 more
```

### Code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentTabsPager {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    //

    }
    }
    public class FragmentTabsPager extends BaseFragmentActivity {
        protected TabHost       mTabHost;
        ViewPager               mViewPager;
        TabsAdapter             mTabsAdapter;

        TabWidget               mTabsBar;
        boolean                 mTabBarHidden = false;
        int                     mTabBarHeight = 0;
        TextView layout_Title;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabsBar  = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

      // 

    }
    public class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
                Log.d("HardwareAcceleration","Hardware acceleration enabled");
            }
            contentId = LAYOUT_ID;
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();     
            View v = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);   
            SetBaseView(v);
        }

    }


    R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager
    -------------------------------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlTabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/TabbackGround"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:background="#00000000" />

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="0dip" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: gonna need to see your code before anyone can help you with this

Comment: @Darrell Code updated. Seeing the Android source code ViewConfiguration.java for Android 4.2 the following line where null pointer is at "display.getRealSize(size);" .

Comment: I can't seem to see the line you are talking about...

Comment: @Darrell I am talking about the null pointer exception shown in stack trace which points to Viewconfiguration.java file in android source code.

Comment: It says it is at line 285: `at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:285)` can you point out which line this is?

Comment: @Darrell there is no such code in my app. It an internal call. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java?av=f